# Android list doesn't show data from external database with PHP files. Error: type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json, database

I have a problem. My Android application doesn't show a list from a external database. I have some PHP files that make the connection (it works!). This is the kind of error I get:

```
$result of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
 W/System.err:     at keepklm.klmsurveyv2.StartActivity.showUser(StartActivity.java:51)
 W/System.err:     at keepklm.klmsurveyv2.StartActivity.access$100(StartActivity.java:29)
 W/System.err:     at keepklm.klmsurveyv2.StartActivity$1GetJSON.onPostExecute(StartActivity.java:93)
 W/System.err:     at keepklm.klmsurveyv2.StartActivity$1GetJSON.onPostExecute(StartActivity.java:79)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I think the mistake is somewhere in the java code on the startActivity page?
Here is my PHP code:

getAllUser.php:

```
    <?php
    echo '$result';
    //Importing Database Script 
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //Creating sql query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM User";

    //getting result 
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    //creating a blank array 
    $result = array();

    //looping through all the records fetched
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

        //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
        array_push($result, array(
            "id" => $row['id'],
            "firstName" => $row['firstName'],
            "lastName" => $row['lastName'],
            "department" => $row['department'],
            "company" => $row['company']
        ));
    }

    //Displaying the array in json format 
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));

    mysqli_close($con);
```

dbConnect.php:

```
    <?php

    /* 
     * Making connection with the external database
     */

     //Defining Constants
     define('HOST','secret');
     define('USER','secret');
     define('PASS','secret');
     define('DB','secret');

     //Connecting to Database
     $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

Here are my android java codes:

startActivity.java:

```
        package keepklm.klmsurveyv2;

                import android.app.ProgressDialog;
                import android.content.Intent;
                import android.os.AsyncTask;
                import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.util.Log;
                import android.view.Menu;
                import android.view.MenuItem;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.widget.AdapterView;
                import android.widget.ListAdapter;
                import android.widget.ListView;
                import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
                import android.widget.Toast;

                import org.json.JSONArray;
                import org.json.JSONException;
                import org.json.JSONObject;

                import java.util.ArrayList;
                import java.util.HashMap;

                import keepklm.klmsurveyv2.database.external.Config;
                import keepklm.klmsurveyv2.database.external.RequestHandler;

        public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

            private ListView listView;
            private String JSON_STRING;
            public String name;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                getJSON();
            }


            private void showUser(){
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
                    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

                    for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
                         name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_FIRSTNAME);

                        HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                        employees.put(Config.TAG_ID,id);
                        employees.put(Config.TAG_FIRSTNAME,name);
                        list.add(employees);
                        Log.v("hoi", "Json value :" + name);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        StartActivity.this, list, R.layout.list_item_custom,
                        new String[]{Config.TAG_ID,Config.TAG_FIRSTNAME},
                        new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.firstName});

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            private void getJSON(){
                class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

                    ProgressDialog loading;
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        loading = ProgressDialog.show(StartActivity.this,"Fetching Data","Wait...",false,false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                        super.onPostExecute(s);
                        loading.dismiss();
                        JSON_STRING = s;
                        showUser();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                        String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);
                        return s;
                    }
                }

                GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
                gj.execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LanguageActivity.class);
                HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String empId = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
                intent.putExtra(Config.USER_ID,empId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Config.java:

```
        package keepklm.klmsurveyv2.database.external;

        public class Config {

                //Address of our scripts of the CRUD
                public static final String URL_ADD="secret_link";
                public static final String URL_GET_ALL = "secret_link";
                public static final String URL_GET_USER = "secret_link";
                public static final String URL_UPDATE_USER = "secret_link";
                public static final String URL_DELETE_USER = "secret_link";

                //Keys that will be used to send the request to php scripts
                public static final String KEY_USER_ID = "id";
                public static final String KEY_USER_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
                public static final String KEY_USER_LASTNAME = "firstname";
                public static final String KEY_USER_COMPANY = "company";
                public static final String KEY_USER_DEPARTMENT = "department";

                //JSON Tags
                public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
                public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
                public static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "firstName";
                public static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "lastName";
                public static final String TAG_COMPANY = "company";
                public static final String TAG_DEPARTMENT = "department";

                //employee id to pass with intent
                public static final String USER_ID = "emp_id";
            }
```

RequestHandler.java:

```
    package keepklm.klmsurveyv2.database.external;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;


    import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

    public class RequestHandler {

        //Method to send httpPostRequest
        //This method is taking two arguments
        //First argument is the URL of the script to which we will send the request
        //Other is an HashMap with name value pairs containing the data to be send with the request
        public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                      HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
            //Creating a URL
            URL url;

            //StringBuilder object to store the message retrieved from the server
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                //Initializing Url
                url = new URL(requestURL);

                //Creating an httmlurl connection
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //Configuring connection properties
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                //Creating an output stream
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

                //Writing parameters to the request
                //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String response;
                    //Reading server response
                    while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                        sb.append(response);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String sendGetRequest(String requestURL){
            StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(requestURL);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String s;
                while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(s+"\n");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String sendGetRequestParam(String requestURL, String id){
            StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(requestURL+id);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String s;
                while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(s+"\n");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            return result.toString();
        }
    }
```

Here is my android xml code:

start_activity.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".StartActivity">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

list_item_custom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you log the JSON_STRING variable in your showUser() method pls ?

Comment: I get this: $result{"result":[{"id":"01","firstName":"Sanne","lastName":"Strikkers","department":"IT","company":"KLM"},{"id":"02","firstName":"Thieme","lastName":"","department":"IT","company":"KLM"},{"id":"03","firstName":"Thomas","lastName":"","department":"IT","company":"KLM"},{"id":"04","firstName":"June","lastName":"","department":"IT","company":"KLM"},{"id":"05","firstName":"Jussi","lastName":"","department":"IT","company":"KLM"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid json returned from the server side. You append the "$result" prefix to your json (echo '$result') so you get exception when you are trying to create json object with this invalid json string.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel so stupid. Just a little mistake. I forget to delete that echo...